# How to access blobs and read excel files using pyhton in AzureFunction

Tags: azure

I would like to use python in azure function to read these excel files in this blob storage. i would like to know how to access this folder of blob in the easiest way and the python code to read the excel files.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IlRs.png)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use [input bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-input)

in your function.json add bindings

```
{
      "name": "inputblob",
      "type": "blob",
      "dataType": "binary",
      "path": "blob/path/filename.csv",
      "connection": "MyStorageConnectionAppSetting",
      "direction": "in"
    },
```

Then function

import logging
import azure.functions as func

```
# The input binding field inputblob can either be 'bytes' or 'str' depends
# on dataType in function.json, 'binary' or 'string'.
def main(queuemsg: func.QueueMessage, inputblob: bytes) -> bytes:
    logging.info(f'Python Queue trigger function processed {len(inputblob)} bytes')
    return inputblob
```

Comment: I have tried following the Microsoft documentation, but it does not work. I am very sorry, but I would appreciate some more explanation.

Ultimately, I want to convert each excel file to a csv file as shown in the picture. I understand the python code to convert the files, but I am finding it difficult to do this with AzureFunction and would appreciate your guidance. Best regards.

Comment: @otaki I am sorry but i tried and it works. If you want people to help you must provide what you are doing and what is not working. Otherwise no one will help as its too broad sorry.

Comment: Import "azure.functions" could not be resolved
The above Error statement is displayed.
Perhaps import azure.functions as func here